# Access Cloud SQL from App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-sql, app-engine-flexible, cloud-sql-proxy

I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/openjdk

...

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS $SERVICE_OPTS -jar Server.jar
```

This starts a Spring Boot project, served by a Tomcat server. In order to start, spring boot needs database access for it's JPA components:

```
# Spring Datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:google:mysql://INSTANCE_NAME/DATABASE?user=db-user&password=*******
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=db-user
spring.datasource.password=********
```

My `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex

beta_settings:
     cloud_sql_instances: INSTANCE_NAME
```

I still haven't figured out how to establish the cloud sql connection. Any ideas?

Comment: I already went through all topics regarding this issue. I still haven't found a solution to my problem yet.

Comment: Please follow the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-cloud-sql The key is that you need to use the mysql-socket-factory library.

Comment: `spring.datasource.url` should just be the uri: `jdbc:mysql://<ip>:<port>/<db>`. If you are proxying from local machine, you can just do `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdb`.